# sort ruby hash by specific key

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a ruby hash like this

```
 {"id"=>62, "name"=>"Wine and Spirits"}
 {"id"=>63, "name"=>"Tobacco"}
 {"id"=>64, "name"=>"Printing"}
 {"id"=>65, "name"=>"Information Services"}
 {"id"=>66, "name"=>"Business Supplies and Equipment"}
```

How do I sort this by name? I tried

```
 categories.sort_by {|_key, value, _key1, value1| value1}
```

But that did not work

Comment: That's not a hash.  It's 5 hashes.  Do you want to sort an array of those 5 hashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to sort an array of hashes:

```
def sort_by_name(hashes)
  hashes.sort_by { |h| h["name"] }
end
```

Comment: Thanks that worked!!! newbie to Ruby! thats right..its an array of hashes. Ruby does not seem to print arrays with `[..]` in `puts` like python :thinking_face:

Comment: Depends how you print them. `p stuff` and `puts stuff` do different things. `puts` prints array elements as separate lines. `p` gives more of a debuggy output.